# How to configure ament python linters in CMakeLists?

Tags: ros, python, ament, colcon, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a ROS2 Eloquent C++ package with some python files (for example, python launch scripts) which I would like to lint.

I have the linters included in the packages.xml

`<test_depend>ament_cmake_pep257</test_depend>`

And have them running in the test section of the CMakeLists

`ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()`

The linters are running and correctly when I run `colcon test` and are failing my *.launch.py because they violate certain rules I don't want to enforce. How do I pass in an ignore list for these?

For example, how would have `colcon test` replicate the results of `ament_pip257 --ignore D400`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351012/how-to-configure-ament-python-linters-in-cmakelists?/) by [nbbrooks](https://answers.ros.org/users/2496/nbbrooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2020-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with you it's underdocumented. It *is* documented though, at least for `ament_cmake_flake8`, but it's probably not in a place casual users would look (ie: the CMake function documentation). See [here](https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/ecaf9ab8d03ebedb2cdfcb45ce89b5416a26c4bd/ament_cmake_flake8/cmake/ament_flake8.cmake#L15-L37).

There should be no need to overwrite the default configuration. You can't use the convenience "ament auto lint" etc functionality any more I believe, but the following should allow you to specify the location of a custom configuration file:

```
  find_package(ament_cmake_flake8 REQUIRED)
  ament_flake8(
    [..]
    CONFIG_FILE /absolute/path/to/your/config.ini
    [..]
    <paths to files>
 )
```

Without trying to "gold plate" it: it's not entirely 'strange' for a CMake developer to expect his users to read the doc strings on CMake functions he makes available.

You could consider contributing a tutorial for this though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's so sad that there's no information about this anywhere (at least I haven't found any).
This should be explained in the official documentation.

I have very little to add and it's sooo hacky, but let's see.
I haven't found a solution for pep257 yet, but I did for flake8. It has a default configuration file that you can overwrite globally. Since I develop from docker, it's done automatically. I have my custom config file in the project and in the Dockerfile I have a line that copies it to the default config file with my own.

My custom config file:

```
 [flake8]
 extend-ignore = B902,C816,D100,D101,D102,D103,D104,D105,D106,D107,D203,D212,D404,I202,E266
 import-order-style = google
 max-line-length = 99
 show-source = true
 statistics = true
```

The command in the Dockerfile

```
COPY ament_flake8.ini /opt/ros/humble/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ament_flake8/configuration/ament_flake8.ini
```

---

Originally posted by [redvinaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/51531/redvinaa/) with karma: 11 on 2023-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-03-05**:
See [ros2/demos/composition/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/6660fbc7da3878fdbdcb1b400a8a6089d5730099/composition/CMakeLists.txt#L204-L209) for an example (which doesn't pass `CONFIG_FILE`, but the idea is similar).

Note that `ament_pep257` supports similar-ish config options, but that's just the Python package. The CMake wrapper for that (ie: `ament_cmake_pep257`) does *not* currently allow callers to set any configuration ([here](https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/ecaf9ab8d03ebedb2cdfcb45ce89b5416a26c4bd/ament_cmake_pep257/cmake/ament_pep257.cmake#L15-L21)).

Perhaps mimicking how `ament_cmake_flake8` supports this could make for a great contribution.